# how does zoom out works in data augmentation?

Tags: keras, data-augmentation

how does zoom out works in data augmentation?

I'm reading a doc on data augmentation in Keras ,and it says that `randomZoom(0.2)` zooms in and out by a factor in rage of 20%. how does zoom out works? does it add white border to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it mirrors the image in borders; so it is like putting smaller versions of the image around the image(having 9 smaller images together) and then cropping the big image with the size of the original image.